# twitter like url and htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Below is my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?url=$1  
</IfModule>
```

I am trying to do the fancy twitter url.

www.mywebsite.com/home rather than www.mywebsite.com/home.php

in my index.php code its like this:

```
<?php

$key=$_GET['url'];

if($key=='index')
{
include('welcome.php'); // welcome page
}
else if($key=='login')
{
include('login.php'); // Login page
}
else
{
include('index.php'); // go back to index.php
}
?>
```

this keeps giving me a an invalid 404 error. and when I output:
`echo $key` it shows like this: `index.php` not `index`

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Check this [router class](https://github.com/dannyvankooten/AltoRouter/blob/master/AltoRouter.php) out.

Answer (score 1):

That's the worst way you make url friendly because if you have 1000 pages you'll have to create a "case" for him in the "switch".
And if you do a "require_once" passing as parameter the $key, you will be with a vulnerability, known as LFI ([Local File Inclusion](http://hakipedia.com/index.php/Local_File_Inclusion)).

What I recommend is for you to study or use REST micro-frameworks like Slim, Respect/Rest, Aura Router, and others.

Look for Restful Routes.

Examples? [Slim Documentation](http://docs.slimframework.com/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for .htaccess code to hide `.php` extension then this should work:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```